# Datagridview CellFormatting Issue

Tags: .net, datagridview

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, and creating one winform desktop application.
I've fetched the data from database and bind the grid using dataview. After that I've manually add 2-3 columns for providing Edit/Delete functionality for records.
For these edit/delete columns I've used DatagridviewImageColumn. And on CellFormatting event I'm loading images based on data.

The issue is I'm facing following issues....
1. This code does not work perfectly on form Load event, don't know why??? i.e. CellFormatting event is not working properly. And when I press refresh button (Which will call same function) the grid bind successfully including CellFormatting event code.
2. When I run single form (customer master) then this code works fine even with form load event, but When I add same form as MDI child then I'm getting above error!!!

please help

```
 private void FillCompanies(bool isActive)
    {
        CompanyController CompanyController = new CompanyController();
        try
        {
            this.dgvCompanys.DataSource = DBNull.Value;
            dv = null;
            this.dgvCompanys.Columns.Clear();
            DataTable dt = CompanyController.GetCompanies(isActive);
            dv = dt.DefaultView;
            this.dgvCompanys.VirtualMode = true;
            this.dgvCompanys.DataSource = dv;
            //this.dgvCompanys.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

            DataGridViewImageColumn colEdit = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            colEdit.HeaderText = "Edit";
            colEdit.Image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Work\MyPrj\MyPrj\Content\Images\Ico\edit.ico");
            this.dgvCompanys.Columns.Add(colEdit);
            this.dgvCompanys.Columns[gridColEdit].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

            DataGridViewImageColumn colDelete = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            colDelete.HeaderText = "Delete";
            colDelete.Image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Work\MyPrj\MyPrj\Content\Images\Ico\delete.ico");
            this.dgvCompanys.Columns.Add(colDelete);
            this.dgvCompanys.Columns[gridColDelete].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            //Image.FromFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Images\\RefreshIco_24.png");

            DataGridViewImageColumn colActive = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            colActive.HeaderText = "Active";
            this.dgvCompanys.Columns.Add(colActive);
            colActive.Image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Work\MyPrj\MyPrj\Content\Images\Ico\active.ico");
            this.dgvCompanys.Columns[gridColActiveImage].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.dgvCompanys.Columns[gridColName].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            this.dgvCompanys.Columns[gridColID].Visible = false;
            this.dgvCompanys.Columns[gridColDataActive].Visible = false;
            this.dgvCompanys.Columns[gridColDataDelete].Visible = false;
            //End With
            this.dgvCompanys.Refresh();
            //dv.RowFilter = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error occurred : " + ex.Message.ToString(), "Application Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Above is the code for fill the grid on form load. Below is the code which is not working properly after form load, but when I click refresh button and call same code it will work properly...

```
private void dgvCompanys_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        bool action = false;
        if (e.ColumnIndex == gridColEdit)
        {
            frmCompany objCompany = new frmCompany(Convert.ToInt64(this.dgvCompanys.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[gridColID].Value.ToString()));
            objCompany.ShowDialog();
            action = true;
        }
        else if (e.ColumnIndex == gridColDelete)
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure, you want to delete this record?", "Delete Record?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                DeleteCompany(Convert.ToInt64(this.dgvCompanys.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[gridColID].Value.ToString()), e.RowIndex);
                action = true;
            }
        }
        else if (e.ColumnIndex == gridColActiveImage)
        {
            bool currStatus = Convert.ToBoolean(this.dgvCompanys.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[gridColDataActive].Value.ToString());
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure, you want to " + (currStatus == true ? "Deactivate" : "Activate") + " this record?", "Delete Record?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                InactiveCompany(Convert.ToInt64(this.dgvCompanys.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[gridColID].Value.ToString()), currStatus, e.RowIndex);
                action = true;
            }
        }

        if (action)
        {
            RefreshGridFilter();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello @Jade I've edit the post, please see code is is still not working....

Comment: Anybody can please help on this?